# ES6 Chaining Access Next Method's Content

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with ES6 Class Chaining. I have a class as in the example. I want to access prefix()'s value. I want to use prefix()'s value in group(), get() and post(). How can I do that?

```js
class Test {

  constructor() {
    this.prefixValue = null
  }

  get(path, controller) {
    console.log(path, controller)
    return this
  }

  post(path, controller) {
    console.log(path, controller)
    return this
  }

  group(cb) {
    cb()
    console.log(this.prefixValue)
    return this
  }

  prefix(prefix) {
    this.prefixValue = prefix
    console.log(this.prefixValue)
    return this
  }

}

module.exports = new Test()
```

```js
import Test from './router.js'

Test.get('/', 'IndexController.find')

Test.group(() => {
  Test.get('/', 'MovieController.find')
  Test.post('/', 'MovieController.create')
}).prefix('/movies')
```

Comment: call first prefix and then call groups

Comment: I know that way. But I don't want to use that way.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work if you try to use the prefix before you've set it.  So, if you're not willing to set the prefix first, there's NO point to this question at all.  You can't use a property of the object that you haven't set yet.

Comment: Then may be if you're gonna use prefix inside cb, just save cb in this.cb = cb and call it only after prefix will be set, otherwise it is not possible

Comment: …the only alternative would be to not use the `.prefixValue` immediately, i.e. to defer the `console.log` calls inside `get()` and `post()`.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your logic. You should call `.prefix` first because calling `.group` makes no sense without context. Maybe you should create `group` more generic, so it can group routes not only by prefix but also request type etc.

Comment: Can you give me some example in code? Because I didn't understand your answers. :)

Comment: I think the problem here is that you aren't showing us the point of the prefix.  You don't show it being used in the `get` or `post` so it's unclear what it's for.  With the context of what the real problem is that you're trying to solve we might be able to offer you better design ideas.  Without that context, the only answer here is that you can't use the prefix before you set it.

Comment: prefix will be used for post('/auth/sign-in') and post('/auth/sign-up'). You can see the prefix there is actually 'auth'.

Comment: They're saying that's not possible. But Adonis.js done this. How are they done this?